# redirect to a subpage as the homepage in a fuel CMS website

Tags: codeigniter, fuelcms

I'm using fuel CMS for the first time -- I'm wondering how to set a redirect in the `/index.php` so when you navigate to the website base URL, your redirect to a `/subpage/` the subpage will always act as *home*.

**Note:** Normal PHP redirects and meta html redirects DO **NOT** WORK. I just get `'redirect loop error'` I guess due to the architecture of the CMS modules etc. Something like even after redirected, files from `index.php` and `header.php` are re-read so you get caught in a redirect.

Anyone familiar with the framework, any pointers would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: FuelPHP and FuelCMS have nothing to do with one another.......FuelCMS is based on CI.

Comment: OK. I have removed that tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* I got **it**! 
(for those who care.. or for more importantly, to the masses who do not!)

```
$config['aggressive_redirects'] = array(
                                    '/' => array('/solutions', TRUE, 302)
                                    );
```

Via documentation.. http://docs.getfuelcms.com/general/redirects let's see how this performs.